# Binary char array to its two complement

Tags: c

Program takes in character array of a binary number and changes the values in place to its twos complement. I compiled and error states I am missing a punctuation mark somewhere.. Ok thanks I fixed the semicolon on line two and now I'm getting undefined reference to twos complement any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void twosComplement(char binaryString[]);



int main()
{
    char binaryString[33];
    scanf("%32s",binaryString); //takes in Binary Number 32 bits max
    twoscomplement(binaryString);//calls function
    printf("%s\n", binaryString);//prints twosComplement of Binary Number input
    return 0;  
}


void twosComplement(char binaryString[])
{
    char zero = '0'; 
    char one ='1';
    int numBits;
     for( numBits = 0; binaryString[numBits]; ++ numBits) //iterates through all the characters
     {
         if( numBits == one)// changes value if character == '1'
         {
                    binaryString[numBits]= zero;
         }

         else 
         {
                    binaryString[numBits]= one;  // changes value is character doesn't == '1'                                       assuming user only input '0's and '1's
         }

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: C is case sensitive. In line 3 of main you have twos **c** ompliment, but your function is twos **C** ompliment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second line you are missing a semicolon `;`:

```
void twosComplement(char binaryString[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing semicolom while declaring function line 2

```
#include <stdio.h>
void twosComplement(char binaryString[]);
```